# P5.Js - how can I change line() color in a while-loop on specific x-values?

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I am doing a small assignment that requires the following:

I have to create a while-loop that draws 30 lines on-screen. Line number 7 and line number 23 should be colored red.

Because I am still trying to figure things out, I try to color the 2 nearest lines from stroke(0); to stroke(255);, but no matter what I try, I cannot get the 2 lines to change color

In this example I tried nesting a while loop, which so far doesn't work. I also tried removing the nested while loop and add an "if" statement with the same variables (x == 40 && x == 60) but still nothings happens. What can I do to fix this?

```
var x = 20;
var stap = 20;
var stop = 600;

function setup () {
  createCanvas(700, 700);
}

function draw () {
  stroke(0);

  while(x < stop) {
    line(x, 60, x, 80);
    x += stap;

    while (x == 40 && x == 60) {
      stroke(255);
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: Since nobody mentioned it: `while (x == 40 && x == 60)` means that the loop keeps running es long `x==40` and `x==60`. Since `x` can't have 2 different values at the same time, the condition is never fulfilled. This means the body of the loop is never executed.

Comment: Crossposted: https://discourse.processing.org/t/change-line-color-in-a-nested-while-loop/7421

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're very close, you just don't need that inner while loop!

For completeness, here's a p5 solution:

```js
var x = 20;
var stap = 20;
var stop = 600;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(700, 700);
}

function draw() {

  while (x < stop) {
    if (x === 20 || x === 40) {
      stroke(255, 0, 0);
    } else {
      stroke(0);
    }

    line(x, 60, x, 80);
    x += stap;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

You said you'd like to get the nearest two to display, those lines are at x position 20 and 40, rather than 40 and 60!

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the stroke color in your if-statement *after* drawing the line. Make sure to first set the colors, then draw whatever you are going to draw.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for a `while loop` is as follows:

```
while (condition) {
  statements to execute while the condition is true
}
```

In your case:

```
while (line_number <= 30) {
  y = step_size * line_number;
  // Determine which color to use
  if (line_number == 7 || line_number == 23) {
    // Set color to RED
    line_color = color(127, 0, 0);
  } else {
    // Set alternate color
    line_color = color(127, 127, 127);
  }
  // Set the color to draw the line
  stroke(line_color);
  // Draw a horizontal line
  line(0, y, width, y);
  // Go to the next line
  line_number++;
}
```